# Adding value to range on different sheet from range + subtraction

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have users inputting a specific name and value (from 65-90) in a range E12, E13 respectively.  I'm trying to get the name, from E12 to a range corresponding to the value entered in E13 minus 51, so if the user enters 65 in E13, Sheet2 will reflect the name from E12 on the range of B14.  I was assuming the following code would suffice, but it doesn't seem to.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E13").Value - 51).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E12").Value
End Sub
```

This snippet is intended to be copied and used 20 times on a sheet for potentially 20 entries so the ranges from sheet1 will change.

I may be going about it in a completely wrong fashion so any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I'm not sure if it works... 
Define a variable to

> Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E13").Value

and then use

> variable - 51

in your code. Hope it solves your problem.